# Is there a way to build a Java String using an SLF4J-style formatting function?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I've heard that using StringBuilder is faster than using string concatenation, but I'm tired of wrestling with StringBuilder objects all of the time.  I was recently exposed to the SLF4J logging library and I love the "just do the right thing" simplicity of its formatting when compared with String.format.  Is there a library out there that would allow me to write something like:

```
int myInteger = 42;
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();  // Overrides toString()
String result = CoolFormatingLibrary.format("Simple way to format {} and {}",
    myInteger, myObject);
```

Also, is there any reason (including performance but excluding fine-grained control of date and significant digit formatting) why I might want to use String.format over such a library if it does exist?

Comment: Why doesn't String.format work for you?  The usages between the two are very close.

Comment: I don't know about the performance of String.format, but you may want to use it over any external library to avoid the need of importing dependencies into your application. I will have a short look at the implementation of String.format...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For concatenating strings *one time*, the old reliable `"str" + param + "other str"` is perfectly fine (it's actually converted by the compiler into a `StringBuilder`).

StringBuilders are mainly useful if you have to keep adding things to the String, but you can't get them all into one statement. For example, take a `for` loop:

```
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    str += i + " "; // ignoring the last-iteration problem
}
```

This will run much slower than the equivalent StringBuilder version:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // for extra speed, define the size
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    sb.append(i).append(" ");
}
String str = sb.toString();
```

But these two are functionally equivalent:

```
String str = var1 + " " + var2;
String str2 = new StringBuilder().append(var1).append(" ").append(var2).toString();
```

---

### Having said all that, my actual answer is:

Check out [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). Sample code from the Javadocs:

```
int fileCount = 1273;
String diskName = "MyDisk";
Object[] testArgs = {new Long(fileCount), diskName};

MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("The disk \"{1}\" contains {0} file(s).");

System.out.println(form.format(testArgs));
```

Output:

> `The disk "MyDisk" contains 1,273 file(s).`

There is also a static [`format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method which does not require creating a `MessageFormat` object.

All such libraries will boil down to string concatenation at their most basic level, so there won't be much performance difference from one to another.

Comment: This is also my conclusion after the inspection of OpenJDK's implementation of java.util.Formatter.

Comment: Just in this moment I discovered the MessageForamt class and remembered this thread...
Good to see you already knew it.

One hint: actually it is java.text.MessageFormat

Comment: @Andreas: I have no idea how that "util" got in there. I blame the java.gremlins package.

Comment: I am not sure whether it would be correct to always blame java.gremlins. No one ever blames java.starwars.sith.lords nor even java.jucknorris... ;-)

Comment: Note that `MessageFormat` uses `StringBuffer` and not `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 48):

Although the Accepted answer is good, if (like me) one is interested in exactly Slf4J-style semantics, then the correct solution is to use Slf4J's [MessageFormatter](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html)

Here is an example usage snippet:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... params) {
    return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(format, params).getMessage();
}
```

(Note that this example discards a last argument of type `Throwable`)

Comment: exactly what I want

Comment: I don't understand why `MessageFormatter` itself doesn't already accept `Object... params` -- would be convenient to not need to make a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 2):

Plus it worth bearing in min that String.format() is a bad implementation of sprintf done with regexps, so if you profile your code you will see an patterns and int[] that you were not expecting.
MessageFormat and the slf MessageFormmater are generally faster and allocate less junk