# Is there a general string substitution function similar to sl4fj?

Tags: java

With sl4fj if I want to construct a string message there is a nice approach which makes use of substitutions.  For instance, it might be something like:

```
logger.info("Action {} occured on object {}.", objectA.getAction(), objectB);
```

If there are more than a few substitutions required then it is something like:

```
logger.info("Action {} occured on object {} with outcome {}.", 
    new Object[]{objectA.getAction(), objectB, outcome});
```

My question is: Is there a generic way for me to create a string (and not just a slf4j log message)? Something like:

```
String str = someMethod("Action {} occured on object {}.", objectA.getAction(), objectB);
```

or

```
String str = someMethod("Action {} occured on object {} with outcome {}.", 
    new Object[]{objectA.getAction(), objectB, outcome});
```

If it is in the standard Java library, what would that "someMethod" be?

Comment: Thanks to those with answers below. Additionally, I discovered this question had already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114021. Sorry to have posted a more-or-less duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to build a Java String using an SLF4J-style formatting function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114021/is-there-a-way-to-build-a-java-string-using-an-slf4j-style-formatting-function)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

[String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String str = String.format("Action %s occured on object %s.",
   objectA.getAction(), objectB);
```

Or

```
String str = String.format("Action %s occured on object %s with outcome %s.",
   new Object[]{objectA.getAction(), objectB, outcome});
```

You can also use numeric positions, for example to switch the parameters around:

```
String str = String.format("Action %2$s occured on object %1$s.",
   objectA.getAction(), objectB);
```

Comment: Be aware that the performance of String.format can be a factor if you're repeatedly calling and doing a lot of substitutions. I only use it if I'm in need of some of the great format specifications it includes. Otherwise, if I'm just injecting strings I use alternatives.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [MessageFormat.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

E.g.,

```
MessageFormat.format("A sample value {1} with a sample string {0}", 
    new Object[] {"first", 1});
```

or simply

```
MessageFormat.format("A sample value {1} with a sample string {0}", "first", 1);
```

Comment: MessageFormat is very versatile and powerful, but for simple replacements, String.format will likely be simpler and less restricted (eg, MessageFormat requires single quotes to be doubled).

Comment: new Integer(1) replaced with only 1 in above then too will work.

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest to use [org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html). With the help of it one can create a utillity method that uses the exact same formatting style as slf4j:

```
// utillity method to format like slf4j
public static String format(String msg, Object... objs) {
    return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(msg, objs).getMessage();
}

// example usage
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = format("This msg is {} like slf{}j would do. {}", "formatted", 4,
            new Exception("Not substituted into the message"));

    // prints "This msg is formatted like slf4j would do. {}"    
    System.out.println(msg); 
}
```

**Note**: If the last object in the array is an Exception it will not be substituted in the message, just like with an slf4j logger. The Exception would be accessible via `MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(msg, objs).getThrowable()`.

Comment: I’d argue this is not a good general-purpose answer, but actually quite to the point of what was asked, though.

Comment: I find this exactly the right answer. This should be the best in terms of performance.

Comment: Best answer as it uses the exact syntax the question asked for.

Comment: frankly, IMHO this is the _only_ answer that actually matches the original question... beats me why it's ranked on fourth place right now...

Comment: Why a utility method? `MessageFormatter.format("My message {} and {}", "first arg", "second arg").getMessage()`

Comment: @LukeSolar `MessageFormatter.format` only works with 1 or 2 arguments. But your argument could be made for `MessageFormatter.arrayFormat`. But here the signature does not use varargs array. So the utillity method adds the varargs convenience we know from `logger.info`.
Besides that a utillity method helps with DRY. :)

Comment: I see... You could mention that as a first option to improving your answer like `MessageFormatter.arrayFormat("My tree args {} {} {}", new String[]{"one","two","three"});`

Answer (score 28):

If you are looking for a solution where you can replace a bunch of variables in a String with values, you can use [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrSubstitutor.html).

```
 Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";
 StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

It follows a generally accepted pattern where one can pass a map with variables to values along with the unresolved String and it returns a resolved String.

Answer (score 2):

I choose wrap the Log4j2 [ParameterizedMessage](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html) which was originally written for Lilith by Joern Huxhorn:

```
public static String format(final String messagePattern, Object... arguments) {
    return ParameterizedMessage.format(messagePattern, arguments);
}
```

It is focus on message format, unlike SLF4J [MessageFormatter](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.java) which contains unnecessary processing of Throwable.

See the Javadoc:

> Handles messages that consist of a format string containing '{}' to represent each replaceable token, and the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> x = new HashMap<>();
    x.put("1", "1");
    x.put(null, "2");
    x.put("3", "3");

    x.entrySet().stream().peek(hashSet_Map::getPrint).toList();
}

private static void getPrint(Map.Entry<String, String> p) {
    System.out.print(stringFormat(" key={}, value={}", p.getKey(), p.getValue()));
}

private static String stringFormat(String str, Object... obj) {
    str.concat("§");
    List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(str
                    .split("\\{}"))
            .toList();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
            for (int i = 0; i < collect.size(); i++) {
                if (!collect.contains("§")) {
                        strBuilder.append(collect.get(i));
                    if (i < obj.length) {
                        strBuilder.append(obj[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error format";
    };
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).