# How to format strings in Java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Primitive question, but how do I format strings like this:

> "Step {1} of {2}"

by substituting variables using Java? In C# it's easy.

Comment: See [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057960/is-there-a-general-string-substitution-function-similar-to-sl4fj)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 180, accepted):

In addition to String.format, also take a look [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).  The format less terse and a bit closer to the C# example you've provided and you can use it for parsing as well.

For example:

```
int someNumber = 42;
String someString = "foobar";
Object[] args = {new Long(someNumber), someString};
MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat("String is \"{1}\", number is {0}.");
System.out.println(fmt.format(args));
```

A nicer example takes advantage of the varargs and autoboxing improvements in Java 1.5 and turns the above into a one-liner:

```
MessageFormat.format("String is \"{1}\", number is {0}.", 42, "foobar");
```

`MessageFormat` is a little bit nicer for doing i18nized plurals with the choice modifier.  To specify a message that correctly uses the singular form when a variable is 1 and plural otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
String formatString = "there were {0} {0,choice,0#objects|1#object|1<objects}";
MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat(formatString);
fmt.format(new Object[] { new Long(numberOfObjects) });
```

Comment: MessageFormat is for localization purposes, so take care when using it. For example the following code `MessageFormat.format("Number {0}", 1234));` depending on default locale can produce `Number 1,234` instead of `Number 1234`.

Comment: @ataylor : Hello, Sorry but I am little confused. I want to something like that I ll pass Class object that has data & when `{0} it ll take firstname`, when `{1} then lastname`, like so. Is it possible like `{0,choice,0.getFirstName()}` or something like that ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ I don't think so.

Comment: Ok fine, I have refer one .Net project like that I want, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42310/Custom-Formatting-in-NET-Enhancing-String-Format-t, refer this project I am looking like this. If you know any project or packages available like that then please tell me. Thank you

Comment: ❗️ `MessageFormat` is orders of magnitude slower than `String.format` — avoid it unless you plan to live forever. This should **NOT** be the accepted answer.

Comment: `MessageFormat` may be slower, but that may or may not matter depending on what it's used for, and this _is_ a better-fitting answer to the original question.

Answer (score 315):

Take a look at [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Note, however, that it takes format specifiers similar to those of C's printf family of functions -- for example:

```
String.format("Hello %s, %d", "world", 42);
```

Would return "Hello world, 42". You may find [this](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm) helpful when learning about the format specifiers. Andy Thomas-Cramer was kind enough to leave [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) link in a comment below, which appears to point to the official spec. The most commonly used ones are:

- %s - insert a string
- %d - insert a signed integer (decimal)
- %f - insert a real number, standard notation

This is radically different from C#, which uses positional references with an optional format specifier. <strike>That means that you can't do things like:</strike>

```
String.format("The {0} is repeated again: {0}", "word");
```

... <strike>without actually repeating the parameter passed to printf/format.</strike> (see  The Scrum Meister's comment below)

---

If you just want to print the result directly, you may find System.out.printf ([PrintStream.printf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)) to your liking.

Comment: Another option is java.text.MessageFormat, which does accept the {1} style format symbols. String.format()'s format symbols can be similar to C's printf() format symbols -- but can also differ. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax for the full syntax.

Comment: `String.format` can also take numeric positions: `String.format("%2$s %1$s", "foo", "bar");` will output `bar foo`

Comment: Starting from Java 15 it is possible to use String.format directly on the String using [String.formatted()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)). `"Hello %s, %d".formatted("world", 42)`

Answer (score 47):

### New JDK features

These below are available since Java 12+.

##### String templates since Java 21 (as the first preview)

Introduced as [JEP-460](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430) (Preview) in Java 21 and later as [JEP-459](https://openjdk.org/jeps/459) (Second Preview) in Java 22. The API is not definitive and this part of the answer is a subject of changes.

This enhancement brings template processors for performing string interpolation.

- [`STR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringTemplate.html#STR) is statically imported implicitly and interpolated immediatelly:

  ```java
  int x = 10;
  int y = 20;
  // results in "10 + 20 = 30"
  String result = STR."\{x} + \{y} = \{x + y}";
  ```
- [`RAW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringTemplate.html#RAW) must be statically imported explicitly and the interpolation is deffered:

  ```java
  int x = 10;
  int y = 20;
  StringTemplate st = RAW."\{x} + \{y} = \{x + y}";
  ...
  // results in "10 + 20 = 30"
  String result = STR.process(st);
  ```
- `FMT` combines `STR` with Java's `Formatter`:

  ```java
  int x = 10;
  int y = 20;
  // results in "10 + 20 =      30.00"
  String result = FMT."%d\{x} + %d\{y} = %7.2f\{x + y}";
  ```

##### Alternative since Java 15

There is a new instance method called [`String#formatted(Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) as of Java 15.

The internal implementation is the same as [`String#format(String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

> Formats using this string as the format string, and the supplied arguments.

```
String step1 = "one";
String step2 = "two";

// results in "Step one of two"
String string = "Step %s of %s".formatted(step1, step2);
```

**Advantage**: The difference is that the method is not `static` and the formatting pattern is *a string itself* from which a new one is created based on the `args`. This allows chaining to build the format itself first.

**Disadvantage**: There is no overloaded method with `Locale`, therefore uses the default one. If you need to use a custom `Locale`, you have to stick with [`String#format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

---

### Old JDK features

These below are well known before Java 11, but remain relevant until today.

##### String#format

The most frequent way to format a String is using this static method, that is long available since Java 5 and has two overloaded methods:

- [`String#format(String format, Object args...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))
- [`String#format(Locale l, String format, Object args...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

The method is easy to use and the `format` pattern is defined by underlying [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
String step1 = "one";
String step2 = "two";

// results in "Step one of two"
String string = String.format("Step %s of %s", step1, step2);
```

You can pass a `Locale` to respect the language and regional specification. Refer to this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431949/3764965 (credits to [Martin Törnwall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443265/martin-t%C3%B6rnwall)).

##### MessageFormat

The [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class is available since the first version of Java and is suitable for internationalization. In the simplest form, there is a static method for formatting:

- [`MessageFormat#format​(String pattern, Object... arguments)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

```
String step1 = "one";
String step2 = "two";

// results in "Step one of two"
String string = MessageFormat.format("Step {0} of {1}", step1, step2);
```

Remember `MessageFormat` follows a specific pattern different from `String#format`, refer to its JavaDoc for more details: [MessageFormat - patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html#patterns).

It is possible to use `Locale`, however, one has to instantiate the object of the class and pass it to the constructor since the static method above uses the default constructor with the default locale. Refer to this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432100/3764965 (credits to [ataylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190201/ataylor)).

##### StringBuilder and String concatenation

These are well known and described anywhere else.

---

### Non-JDK solutions

There are plenty of ways to format Strings using external libraries. They add little to no benefit if the libraries are imported solely for the purpose of String formatting. Few examples:

- Apache Commons: [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html), examples in its JavaDoc.
- Cactoos: [`FormattedText`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.16/org/cactoos/text/FormattedText.html), examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cactoos#formatted-string).
- Interestingly, Guava doesn't plan to add formatting or templating features: [#1142](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1142#issuecomment-61352720).
- ... and other custom implementations.

<sup>Feel free to add more, however, I find no reason to further expand this section.</sup>

Comment: Nice! Too bad I'm still working with Java 8 right now. We're debating to move either to Java 11 or Java 14 in the next year or so... so we probably won't be able to use this feature for another 3-5 years.

Comment: I'd be more optimistic. The LTS version will be Java 17 as of September 2021 so this feature might get handy. I haven't noticed such structural changes like the modular system between the 8 and 9 versions so I believe the migration will be faster :))

Answer (score 15):

If you choose not to use String.format, the other option is the + binary operator

```
String str = "Step " + a + " of " + b;
```

This is the equivalent of

`new StringBuilder("Step ").append(String.valueOf(1)).append(" of ").append(String.valueOf(2));`

Whichever you use is your choice. StringBuilder is faster, but the speed difference is marginal. I prefer to use the `+` operator (which does a `StringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(X)))` and find it easier to read.

Comment: If you're going to neg rep me, please explain why.

Comment: 1) In response to a question on string formatting, you explain how the `+` operator works. 2) Your explanation isn't even accurate. `+` is equivalent to using `StringBuilder`, not `String.concat`. [(Way too much info on this.)](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/06/java-string-concatenation/)

Answer (score 9):

I've wrote my simple method for it :

```
public class SomeCommons {
    /** Message Format like 'Some String {0} / {1}' with arguments */
    public static String msgFormat(String s, Object... args) {
        return new MessageFormat(s).format(args);
    }
}
```

so you can use it as:

```
SomeCommons.msgFormat("Step {1} of {2}", 1 , "two");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class StringFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(String.format("%-15s%03d",s1,x));
            }
            System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

> outpot
>   "================================"
>   ved15space123
>   ved15space123
>   ved15space123
>   "================================

**Java solution**

- The "-" is used to left indent
- The "15" makes the String's minimum length it takes up be 15
- The "s" (which is a few characters after %) will be substituted by our String
- The 0 pads our integer with 0s on the left
- The 3 makes our integer be a minimum length of 3

Comment: You're right http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 5):

### *JEP 430: String Templates (Preview)*

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a [preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12).

Here is an example use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.  For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Sad, why it's so long to have this... God Please... :') Java 17 doesn't have this then..

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto No version of Java has this yet. Only in preview in Java 21. To understand *preview*, see [*JEP 12: Preview Features*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12).

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me. I needed to create urls for a REST client dynamically so I created this method, so you just have to pass the restURL like this

```
/customer/{0}/user/{1}/order
```

and add as many params as you need:

```
public String createURL (String restURL, Object ... params) {       
    return new MessageFormat(restURL).format(params);
}
```

You just have to call this method like this:

```
createURL("/customer/{0}/user/{1}/order", 123, 321);
```

The output

> "/customer/123/user/321/order"

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)'s [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) provides a simple and readable way to format `String`s with named variables.

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;
// ...
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
values.put("target", "lazy dog");
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(values);
String result = sub.replace("The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.");
// "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
```

This class supports providing default values for variables.

```
String result = sub.replace("The number is ${undefined.property:-42}.");
// "The number is 42."
```

To use recursive variable replacement, call `setEnableSubstitutionInVariables(true);`.

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("b", "c");
values.put("ac", "Test");
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(values);
sub.setEnableSubstitutionInVariables(true);
String result = sub.replace("${a${b}}");
// "Test"
```

Answer (score 2):

## `java.util.Formatter`

Java has the [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) which is used internally for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) formatting methods. It's quite powerful, albeit more complex to use.

Here is a guide for what you should use depending on your version of Java.

### Java 15 and later

Call instance method [`String#formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)).

```java
// Sequential string arguments
"foo %s baz %s".formatted("bar", "foobar");

// Indexed string arguments
"foo %1$s baz %2$s".formatted("bar", "foobar");
```

### Java 5 to Java 14

Call static method [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

```java
// Sequential string arguments
String.format("foo %s baz %s", "bar", "foobar");

// Indexed string arguments
String.format("foo %1$s baz %2$s", "bar", "foobar");
```

### Java 4 and earlier

```java
MessageFormat.format("foo {0} baz {1}", "bar", "foo");
```

That last example is for completeness' sake, and you should not be using it since it's the slowest of all options.

Comment: I still find the earliest solution (the latest mentioned) as the best one in terms of flexibility as you can mention a placeholder multiple times without repeating the argument. Also, it is easy to follow the attributes as they are numbered.

On the other hand, the Java 15 approach does not support `Locale` and is not meant as a full substitution to `String#format`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function it does just the right thing. Interpolate a word starting with `$` with the value of the variable of the same name.

```
private static String interpol1(String x){
    Field[] ffield =  Main.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String[] test = x.split(" ") ;
    for (String v : test ) {
        for ( Field n: ffield ) {
            if(v.startsWith("$") && ( n.getName().equals(v.substring(1))  )){
                try {
                    x = x.replace("$" + v.substring(1), String.valueOf( n.get(null)));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) helper class from Apache Commons Text provides named variable substitution

```
Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
String resolved = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap).replace("The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.");
System.out.println(resolved); // The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```