# The method println(int) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 1;
    int result = num1 * num2; 
    System.out.println("%d x %d = %d\n",num1,num2,result);
}
```

I am trying to printout a form like "1 * 10 = 10". However I get an error:

> The method println(int) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)".

I don't know what's the problem and how should I change it?

Comment: You are looking for `format`instead of `println`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to format string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-string-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(num1+" x "+num2+" = "+result+"\n");
```

**UPDATE:** Some of you are saying this concatenation method is slower than other methods. You are right, it is slower, but does it really matter for this example?

This method is usually used to debug, not as part of the final code, and usually only once or twice on the whole code.

Faster method:

```
System.out.printf("%d x %d = %d\n",num1,num2,result);
```

Comment: don't downvote this answer please! it's a nice alternative (maybe a bit slower which usually makes no difference since it's used for debug purposes mainly) which is used very commonly

Comment: Thanks @ParkerHalo for that answer, forgot to mention it, already updated.

Comment: @Mayuso I just tried it and it's only 10-15% so not really relevant ;)

Comment: @ParkerHalo That would a problem in a loop, or if you use the method many (Hundreds, thousands) times in your code, not this case. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mayuso exactly the difference is just visible with 100,000 runs or more ;) and even then it's only like 400 ms... personally I use `println()` much more than `printf()` but that's just opinion based!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using `system.out.format` like this:

```
System.out.format("%s x %s = %s\n",num1,num2,result);
```

Your current solution using `println` isn't working as `println` cannot format text output in this way, you would have to (as others have said) concatenate the string using the "+" operator. It's slower in most cases but for debugging purposes I shouldn't imagine it's much of a problem either way.

Answer (score 6):

There's a `printf(...)` method in `System.out`!

```
System.out.printf("%d x %d = %d\n",num1,num2,result);
```

Answer (score 4):

The Method your using `(System.out.println`) isn't made for multiple parameters. By using `,` you try to give it multiple parameters. You need the `+`-operator.

Applied to your code it should look like that:

```
System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + result);
```

Maybe you should look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()). This is the Documentation of PrintStream. As you can see there is no method like you are using it(`System.out.println(String, Int, Int ,Int);`).

Answer (score 4):

One of the simple way is that you can use the concatenation operation '+' instead of ',' to print

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = 0;
        for(int num1 = 1;num1 < 10;num1++){
            for(int num2 = 1;num2 <10;num2++){
                result = num1 * num2; 
                System.out.println(num1+"x"+num2+"="+result);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[println as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) currently accepts 0 or 1 arguments, reason for the mentioned error.

You need to either concatenate or use String Format to format the result if you intend to use println(only):

- String Format:
  `System.out.println(String.format("%d x %d = %d\n",num1,num2,result));`
- String Concatenation using StringBuffer:
  `StringBuffer resltBuffer = new StringBuffer(num1).append(" x ").append(num2).append(" = ").append(result);
      System.out.println(resltBuffer.toString());`

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here


    int first = 20;
    int second = 30;
    System.out.println("before swap");
    System.out.println("first value :" +first);
    
    System.out.println("second value: " +second);
    first = first - second;
    second = first + second;
    first = second - first;
    
    System.out.println("after swap");
  System.out.println("first value: " +first);
    
    System.out.println("second value: " +second);
```

remove comma from the print statement

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question. The question is more about how could one provides the correct parameter to printIn() to meet the function signature.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858418)