# Replace string to values from array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a string `The quick * fox jumps * the * dog` and I have an array of strings `String[] array = {"brown", "over", "lazy"}`.

What is the optimal way to replace all `*` to strings from array then first `*` must be replaced to `array[0]` element, the second `*` to `array[1]` etc. Of course solution must allow N replacement for N elements in array.

Comment: The `*` is mandatory? (as opposed to using `%s`)

Comment: @Marvin Yes, I need `*`

Comment: What should happen if there are less array entries than `*`?

Comment: @Marvin In my code that is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `appendReplacement` functionality of Java regex library:

```
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[*]");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Quick * fox jumps * the * dog");
int pos = 0;
String[] array = {"brown", "over", "lazy"};
while (matcher.find()) {
    String replacement = pos != array.length ? array[pos++] : "*";
    matcher.appendReplacement(res, replacement);
} 
matcher.appendTail(res);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/fZO1WA)

Comment: If `pos == array.length`, then just exit the loop, and `appendTail()` will append the rest. Faster than replacing `*` with `*`. --- Note, it is even allowed to skip a call to `appendReplacement()` during the iteration, e.g. if you skip every even `*`, then result will only replace the odd `*` markers.

Comment: @Andreas I'm sure OP will figure out the details of what happens when there are additional placeholders. I just wanted to show him code that does not crash.

Answer (score 4):

```
String.format("The quick * fox jumps * the * dog".replace("*", "%s"), array);
> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

`replace` `*` to `%s` and use `String.format` with the `parameters`, this way works.

see more: [How to format strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java)

Comment: Up-vote for being the *simplest* solution, one valid interpretation of "optimal way".

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regex syntax where * has special meaning. We don't need regex here, `replace` method would be better since it doesn't use regex syntax (it automatically escapes it) and also replaces all occurrences of searched string.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (String x : array) {
    yourString = yourString.replaceFirst("\\*", x);
}
```

Comment: `replaceFirst` is using regex syntax where `*` is metacharacter. To make it literal we need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Write a for-loop iterating over each character in the String `The quick * fox jumps * the * dog` and every time you encounter `*`, you pick the next element of the array while maintaining the current index.

```
String text = "The quick * fox jumps * the * dog";
String[] elements = {"brown", "over", "lazy"};

int idx = 0;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '*')
        result.append(elements[idx++]);
    else
        result.append(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "optimal way" you mean performance, then use a loop with `indexOf()` and build the result using a `StringBuilder`.

Other answers have already covered "simple" (i.e. less code), if that's what you meant by "optimal way".

```
String input = "The quick * fox jumps * the * dog";
String[] array = {"brown", "over", "lazy"};

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
int start = 0;
for (int i = 0, idx; i < array.length; i++, start = idx + 1) {
    if ((idx = input.indexOf('*', start)) < 0)
        break;
    buf.append(input.substring(start, idx)).append(array[i]);
}
String output = buf.append(input.substring(start)).toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

This code will silently accept too many or too few values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases you need to reconstruct the String, and the best way to do so is to use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Two ways to do so :

**First**

- Iterate by characters over the string and add it to the StringBuilder if it's not `*`
- If the character is `*`, add the string at index variable that represents the pointer to the strings array
- Increase index by 1.

**Second**

- Split the original String over `*` using [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, this gives you an array of strings of the original String without the *
- Iterate once over the two arrays at the same time, add the item of the array of splits and then add the corresponding index at the second replacement array.