# Printing an attribute inside quotes

Tags: java, attributes

I want to print an attribute of a class I am making , but I need it to be printed inside quotes `" "`.

I know it has something to with Escape Sequences but a similar post I found suggested using `"\"Hello\""` for example to print `"Hello"`... My case is a bit more complicated cause I don't know beforehand the value of the attribute I want to print. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't make a function that make any String into a Quote. Exanple

```
public static String quotePrinter(String myQuote)
{
    return "\"" +myQuote+ "\"";
}

    String myQuote = "Hello World";
    System.out.println(quotePrinter(myQuote));
```

And the output

```
"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand corretly want you want but take a look at the answers from @ataylor and @Martin Törnwall [How to format strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java) for String interpolation