# Pass parameters to URL placeholders in java

Tags: java

I am getting the URL dynamically which has few placeholders. But i need to pass the parameters to the placeholders.

Below is the URL which i am getting dynamically

```
http://example.com/name/{name}/age/{age}
```

i need to pass parameters for name and age for the above url. How can we achieve that using java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255518/2861108

Comment: You don't "pass parameters" to a string, and this looks like a URI template. Your tooling most likely has a class for working with them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking Rest Client to call this URL and get response.

**http://example.com/name/{name}/age/{age}**

```
String resourceURL = "http://example.com/name";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceURL + "/swarit/age/20", String.class);
```

I would also suggest to do little research before posting question.