# Is it possibile to compile a Java string with params like Log4J?

Tags: java, log4j, string-concatenation

With Log4J I can compile a string easily with params:

```
log.error("My string with a {} and another one {}",param1,param2);
```

Is there something to compile a String with the same way instead of create a StringBuilder or concat strings?

```
String mystr=compileString("My string with a {} and another one {}",param1,param2);
```

Comment: You could use `String mystr = String.format("My string with a %s and another one %s", param1, param2);` where `%s` indicates a parameter, like you would use `{}` with log4j

Comment: In addition to String.format, also take a look `java.text.MessageFormat`. The format less terse and a bit closer to the C# example you've provided and you can use it for parsing as well... see answer ti earlieer question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432100/5427593