# How use this c sharp syntax example in java?

Tags: java, c#, string

How insert (a) and (b) in string line in java?

```
string a = "David";
string b= "Mike";
Console.WriteLine("This is test for {0} and {1}",a,b);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java

Comment: Thank you, thats what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called "String Interpolation".
Since Java 5 you can use this:

```
String s = String.format("This is test for %s and %s", a, b);
```

Comment: A more direct equivalent of `Console.WriteLine` would be `System.out.printf(...)`