# How to use printf to print small double in Java

Tags: java, printf

```java
double value = 4.507310875086383E-8;
System.out.printf("value is %f%n", value);
System.out.print("value is " + value + "\n");
```

The output:

```
value is 0.000000
value is 4.507310875086383E-8
```

I want to know how to output this number by using `System.out.printf` instead of concatenating strings

Comment: It's my problem, just use `System.out.printf("value is %s%n", value); `

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to print 23 scale so you can do :

```
System.out.printf("value is %.23f%n", value);
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered many times (see [How to format strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java) for example).
There are many correct answers, one of them is using String.format():

```
jshell> String.format("value is %f", value)
$4 ==> "value is 4.507300"
```

From Java 15, you can also use String formatted method:

```
jshell> "%f is may value".formatted(value) 
$6 ==> "4.507300 is may value"
```