# How can I pass field name of a class as parameter to include it in a String?

Tags: java, string, class, field

I'm wondering How can I pass field name of a class as parameter to include it in a String?

For example, let's say I have a class A with this members :

```
public class A {

String name;
String reference;
....

}
```

What I want, is to be able to initialize a string having as parameters
one of the two classe field name to display it dynamically. So for instance, I want to do this :

```
System.out.println("the field {nameField} belong to class A.");
```

And in output I would have this :

```
output : the field name belong to class A.
```

Is that possible in Java ?

Any help would be much appreciated ?

Regards

YT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java)

Comment: ClassA ft = new ClassA();
  Class ftClass = ft.getClass();

  Field[] fields = ftClass.getDeclaredFields();
  for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("the field"+fields[i] +" belong to class A.")
  }http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-list-the-declared-fields-of-a-class.html#:~:text=In%20JavaSW%2C%20it's,%2C%20protected%2C%20and%20private%20fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by use of reflection in Java.
[https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html#:~:text=Reflection%20is%20a%20feature%20in,its%20members%20and%20display%20them](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html#:%7E:text=Reflection%20is%20a%20feature%20in,its%20members%20and%20display%20them).